# Convert a String to String Array in Android

Tags: java, arrays

I have 3 String like this:

1. `["state","in",["assigned", "partially_available"]]`
2. `["state","in",["confirmed", "waiting"]]`
3. `["state","in",["confirmed", "waiting", "assigned"]]`

Now I want to convert each string to 2 arrays with first 2 elements is a array and others elements is a array(Ex: `["state", "in"] ["asigned", "partially_available"]`). Any way to do that? Thank you very much!

Comment: How is this question related to android?

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "[state,in,[assigned, partially_available]]";

s = s.substring(1,s.length()-1); // removes first and last square bracket
String[] sArr = s.split(",(?! )"); // split only the comma which is not followed by a space character

String[] newArr1 = {sArr[0],sArr[1]}; // first array containing ["state","in"]

String temp = sArr[2].substring(1,sArr[2].length()-1); // remove the square brackets from the inner array 

String[] newArr2 = {temp.split(",")[0],temp.split(",")[1]}; // second array containing ["asigned", "partially_available"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

public class TestArray{

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String string = "[state,in,[assigned, partially_available]]";
    String[] tempstr = string.split("\\["); //remove "["
    String arrayFirstElement = tempstr[1].substring(0,tempstr[1].length()-1);
    String arraySecondElement = tempstr[2].substring(0, tempstr[2].length()-2);

    System.out.println("arrayFirstElement : " + arrayFirstElement);
    System.out.println("arraySecondElement : " + arraySecondElement);

    String[] strArray = new String[2];
    strArray[0] = arrayFirstElement;
    strArray[1] = arraySecondElement;
    System.out.println("strArray[0] : " + strArray[0] + " AND strArray[1] : " + strArray[1]);

}
```

}